# Block EXE in a machine

Tags: windows, blocking, executable, visual-studio-2010

How can i block all executables in a machine unless i verify it. I have multiple clients and i want to do it as programatically (I am using Visual-Studio-2010). It can be done through registry using DisallowRun but if i change the name of exe to notepad1.exe ,registry thing will not work. I want to get control of all the exe's present ,like the way antivirus has.

Comment: use group policy to specify a [program whitelist](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/8739/restrict-users-to-run-only-specified-programs-in-windows-7/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Blocking EXE from executing in XP Domain environment](http://serverfault.com/questions/396211/blocking-exe-from-executing-in-xp-domain-environment)

Answer (score 7):

The correct setting Microsoft added for what you need is **AppLocker** by GPO.

You can add policy by filehash, filepublisher or path.

With  the filehash, it's harder for an user to bypass it, unless he get another version, but you could block the publisher too.

Comment: I want to write a code for that.

Comment: It's easier by GPO, but you can use powershell. "Get-AppLockerFileInformation –Directory “\\SERVER\SHARE\FOLDER” -Recurse" will list all .exe with what policy it support in the target path. After we do a policy, "Get-AppLockerFileInformation -Directory \\SHARE\SERVER\FOLDER -Recurse | New-AppLockerPolicy -RuleType Publisher,Hash -User Everyone -RuleNamePrefix TEST -XML | Out-File .\TEST.XML" and after we apply it, "Set-AppLockerPolicy –XMLPolicy .\test.XML"